# Is renting App Store to others for test purpose a good idea?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ios-appstore, certificate

Recently someone on Upwork post a job for renting an App Store account to test a tour application. The post is like, they need to test an app with so many devices and they are running out of their `UUID` limit, hence they need to rent an enterprise App Store account, where they will provide a list of their `UUID` and I have to create provisioning profile and p12 certificate for them.

My question is, is there any possibilities that they could do some illegal activity using my app store provisioning profiles and p12 certificates? Should I take that job or not?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Surely this would violate the Terms of Service of your App Store account.

Comment: Sounds completely fishy and I would stay far away.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica & TJ Luoma Thanks for ensuring the fact. I was assuming the same, that's why post it here just to be confirmed. Stay safe, stay blessed guys!